# Create thumbnails of video in django using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, python, django

Currently i am creating a website where users can upload videos and play them back .
The video upload method works fine , the problem is i am trying to create a thumbnail for each video . Instead of representing videos in "< a > " tags i want them to be a picture that a user can click on and then go to another page to play the video .
I am trying to create unique thumbnails for each video on upload using ffmpeg .
The problem is i get that an
 error reading header "filename" : Invalid data found when processing input.
Any reason behind this ? 
I am currently running on my localhost. 
 **NOTE :** The ffmpeg command is working fine on its own .
 **NOTE :** Environment is : Win10 64 , django 1.10 (python 2.7) ffmpeg is the latest version

Comment: Please show the actual command that you are trying to run (not just the Python code), and the full command-line output from ffmpeg.

Comment: MY COMMAND:subprocess.call("ffmpeg -i "+ uploaded_filename +' -vf  "thumbnail,scale=1080:1080" -frames:v 1 '+ thumbnail_name ,shell=True)
OUTPUT:
libavutil    56. 12.100 / 56. 12.100
libavcodec     58. 15.100 / 58. 15.100
libavformat    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavdevice    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
libavfilter     7. 13.100 /  7. 13.100
libswscale      5.  0.102 /  5.  0.102
libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000017cd729a480] error reading header
output002.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: Please don't use commands but [edit] your question to include that information. And please show the entire output from your call – what is the output of the ffmpeg command that “is working fine on its own”? Could it be that you are running a different version of ffmpeg from Python?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my method to capture a thumbnail by seeking a specific duration into my video,then capturing the frame's photo using this command
**subprocess.call("ffmpeg  -ss 00:0:01 -i "+ uploaded_filename +" -frames:v 1 "+ thumbnail_name ,shell=True)**